# Python Beginner (assistance needed) - Program only outputting one element of a saved list (3.8.1)

Tags: python, python-3.x

### Python Beginner In Need Of Assistance

My program, being a true or false quiz where the user enters data which is saved, works in two parts.

Part #1: Program asks the user how many questions they have. The user then fills out a series of questions and answers for that amount. If the answer provided for a question is not (true) or (false) the program re-demands the answer. The user then saves to use this data in order to study in Part 2.

```
def vf():
        import pickle
        import random
        import os
        os.system('cls')

        v = input("How many questions do you have : ")
        vvff = list()

        for i in range(0, int(v)):
            v = input("Enter question : ")
            while True:
                f = input("Enter answer to that question (true or false) : ")
                if f.lower() in ('true', 'false', 'True', 'False'):
                    continue
                else:
                    print("This answer is invalid, please enter True or False")
        vf = {"question": v, "answer": f}
        vvff.append(vf)

        question_vff = input("Would you like to save (yes or no) ")
        if (question_vff == 'yes'):
                pickle.dump(vvff, open("Save.dat", "wb"))
                print("Saved!")
        if (question_vff == 'no'):
                print ("Please save to use you're data.")
```

Part #2: The user uses the save data from before to answer a true or false quiz. This quiz shuffles the questions and answers and the user answers each of them. If the user gets it right, the program says good job, if they get it wrong the program says wrong answer.

```
def vf2():
        import pickle
        import random
        import os
        os.system('cls')

        vvff = pickle.load(open("Save.dat", "rb"))
        random.shuffle(vvff)

        for f in vvff:
                print(f["question"])
                response = input("What was the answer to that question? : ")
                if (response == f["answer"]):
                        print("Good answer!")
                else:
                        print("Wrong answer...")
                        print("The answer is", f, ".")
        print("The study/quiz session is now over. Either create new data or try again later.")
```

**My problem is that, in part 2, the program is supposed to shuffle the questions from the saved data and ask every single one to the user. However, it only asks for the last question they entered in part 1 of the program. What's causing this and how do I fix it? Help is greatly appreciated.**

Comment: Just wrong tabs... realign `vf = {"question": v, "answer": f}` and `vvff.append(vf)` inside the `for-loop`

Answer (score 0):

There's a little mistakes here and there so I will just go and correct them in one go:

```py
def vf():
    import pickle
    import random
    import os
    os.system('cls')

    n = input("How many questions do you have : ") #Changed v to n to avoid overlap
    vvff = list()

    for i in range(0, int(n)):
        v = input("Enter question : ")
        while True:
            f = input("Enter answer to that question (true or false) : ")
            if f.lower() in ('true', 'false'): #removed capitals, it's already lowercase
                continue
            else:
                print("This answer is invalid, please enter True or False")
        vf = {"question": v, "answer": f} #Moved inside for-loop
        vvff.append(vf) #Moved inside for-loop

    question_vff = input("Would you like to save (yes or no) ")
    if (question_vff == 'yes'):
            pickle.dump(vvff, open("Save.dat", "wb"))
            print("Saved!")
    if (question_vff == 'no'):
            print ("Please save to use you're data.")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:=` for python3.8

```
import os
import pickle
import random
from pathlib import Path

FILE = "Save.dat"


def clear():
    os.system("cls")


def vf():
    clear()
    vvff = []
    for _ in range(int(input("How many questions do you have: "))):
        q = input("\nEnter question: ")
        prompt = "Enter answer to that question (true or false): "
        while (a := input(prompt)).lower() not in ("true", "false"):
            print("This answer is invalid, please enter True or False")
        vvff.append({"question": q, "answer": a})
    tip = "\nWould you like to save [(yes)/no] "
    while input(tip).strip().lower() not in ("yes", "y", ""):
        print("Please save to use your data.\n")
    Path(FILE).write_bytes(pickle.dumps(vvff))
    print("Saved!")


def vf2():
    clear()

    vvff = pickle.loads(Path(FILE).read_bytes())
    random.shuffle(vvff)

    for qa in vvff:
        print(qa["question"])
        response = input("What was the answer to that question? ")
        if (response == qa["answer"]):
            print("Good answer!\n")
        else:
            print("Wrong answer...")
            print(f"The answer is {qa} .\n")
    print("The study/quiz session is now over. Either create new data or try again later.")

def main():
    vf()
    vf2()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```